# BeautifulSoup timing out with certain URL's?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, timeout, python-3.8

I am brand new to using BeautifulSoup and I am running into an odd issue, likely user error, but I am stumped! I am using BeautifulSoup to parse through a webpage, and return the first a tag with an href attribute. When I use the Wikipedia link, it works as expected! However when I use the BestBuy link, it leads to this timeout...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import urllib.request

# url = r"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Front_(World_War_II)"
url = r"https://www.bestbuy.com/site/nintendo-switch-32gb-console-neon-red-neon-blue-joy-con/6364255.p?skuId=6364255"

html_content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')

link = soup.find('a', href=True)

print(link)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scrapper.py", line 8, in <module>
    html_content = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 542, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 502, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1393, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/urllib/request.py", line 1354, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 268, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.8/3.8.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: [Errno 60] Operation timed out
```

Do you guys have any insight as to why this might be happening with only certain URL's? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `BeautifulSoup` doesn't timeout since it doesn't do any `http` requests. What times out is `urllib`, and that could happen for a variety of reasons, e.g. server overload, bad request, etc. Instead of using `urllib` I'd recommend to use the `requests` library: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot scrape all websites using BeautifulSoap, some websites have restrictions. Best practice is always use headers:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'}

url = r"https://www.bestbuy.com/site/nintendo-switch-32gb-console-neon-red-neon-blue-joy-con/6364255.p?skuId=6364255"
req = requests.get(url, headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')
print(soup.prettify())
```

**Output:**

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>
   Access Denied
  </title>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1>
   Access Denied
  </h1>
  You don't have permission to access "http://www.bestbuy.com/site/nintendo-switch-32gb-console-neon-red-neon-blue-joy-con/6364255.p?" on this server.
  <p>
   Reference #18.9f01d517.1595655333.b833c
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can achieve this task using selenium, follow below steps:

Step 1: Download the web driver for chrome:

First check your chrome version(Browser's Menu(triple vertical dots) -> Help -> About Google Chrome

Step 2: Download Driver from [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) according to your chrome browser version(mine is 81.0.4044.138)

Step 3: Once downloaded unzip the file and place chromedriver.exe in the directory where your script is.

Step 4: `pip install selenium`

Now use the below code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import urllib.request

#your website url
site = 'https://www.bestbuy.com/site/nintendo-switch-32gb-console-neon-red-neon-blue-joy-con/6364255.p?skuId=6364255'

#your driver path
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'chromedriver.exe')
#passing website url
driver.get(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

driver.close()
link = soup.find('a', href=True)

print(link)
```

**Output:**

```
<a href="https://www.bestbuy.ca/en-CA/home.aspx">
<img alt="Canada" src="https://www.bestbuy.com/~assets/bby/_intl/landing_page/images/maps/canada.svg"/>
<h4>Canada</h4>
</a>
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks a ton for the in-depth response. It worked like a charm and helped me continue with this project!